Dismissing System Dialogs
is there a way to dismiss System Dialogs (Power Off Popup in this case) and the Notification Panel when they're opened?
Using Accessibility Services I'm getting the event of these actions being done by user , but couldn't find a way to change close or dismiss them
Found this solution on web but it's deprecated now :
Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS

I tried calling startActivity but it doesn't effect the focus on them even when the activity starts

Making some assumptions but unless you have root access, it's largely impossible.
Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS use to be a reliable method but recent versions of Android will not permit it.
There are option but everything is subject to Google Play Policy.

Thanks for help , I achieved it using a Accessibility Service and calling GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK when noticed a window state change from com.android.systemui package name and it works fine

In case of Google Play , it's not a concern to me, as an Iranian I can't publish my apps there anyway

An Accessibility Service can interact with the UI directly. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#using-actions. Either interpret each system dialog individually and close it by performing the right action to dismiss it, or simply do performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK) if that works. There's also a GLOBAL_ACTION_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION_SHADE specifically for that case.
An app that isn't an Accessibility Service can't dismiss these dialogs except in this one case.
